How to Quickly Calculate Days Since Latest Uncovered Sales
I have a large set of data for a company's sales and payments received.
How can I quickly find the latest sale that cannot be covered by the total payments for each customer?
Eg. Suppose the data table looks like this



Date
Customer ID
Type
Amount




2024-01-01
1
SALE
100


2024-01-08
1
PAYMENT
50


2024-01-15
1
SALE
100


2024-01-22
1
PAYMENT
100


2024-01-02
2
SALE
200


2024-01-09
2
SALE
200


2024-01-16
2
PAYMENT
150



For Customer 1, it would be 2024-01-15, since total payment amount is 150, so the first sale gets covered; And for customer 2, it would be 2024-01-02, since the only payment cannot cover its first sale.
So far I use a window function to compute the cumulative sales and total payments. Then use this generated table to compute the latest uncovered sale, and other statistics.
with cumsum_entry as (
    select 
        id, date, customer_id, type, amount,
        sum(amount) filter (where type='PAYMENT') over win_customer
          - sum(amount) filter (where type='SALE') over win_cumsum as cover
    from entry
    window win_customer as (partition by customer_id),
        win_cumsum as (partition by customer_id order by date rows between unbounded proceeding and current row)
)
select 
    customer_id,
    sum(amount) filter (where date >= '2024-01-01') as monthly_total,
    min(date) filter (where cover < 0) as latest_uncovered
from cumsum_entry
where date <= '2024-01-31'
group by customer_id

In fact I store the generated table "cumsum_entry" as a view in PostgreSQL, and use Django's orm to do the rest of the work, but the core logical Is the same as above.
Apparently I am not satisfied with the responding speed(2 seconds for ~10^3 customers / ~10^5 entries). How can I further optimize responding time? (Except upgrading hardware, obviously)

From your description and examples, it appears that you want the earliest uncovered sale, not the latest (2024-01-02 is the earliest uncovered sale for customer 2, and 2024-01-09 is the latest).

nice markdown table

Thanks for correction. It is earliest!

The real question here is how to optimize these calculations without messing with other (maybe future) logic.
Let's assume that records of cumsum_entry cannot be changed and that we will not add entries from the past. In this case, the solution is pretty straightforward:

Let's add a field customer_balance under cumsum_entry now. It will be computed as sum of all previous entries where type='PAYMENT' minus sum of all previous entries where type='SALE'.
We can easily calculate it for all existing records with an obvious linear solution. Also, we add processing it before each saving the new cumsum_entry.
Now we can simply select the first record for each customer, where customer_balance < 0.

It becomes a bit more complicated if you can alter data of records added earlier. In this situation, you are forced to keep all customer_balance values up to date after each change. In fact, all that changes is that you need to batch-update all the records after the change with SET customer_balance + <actual_change>.
If the amount of such records becomes too big, I believe, you should consider a solution which only stores sales and payments in PostgreSQL, but maintain the effective data structure for these computations itself on RAM. The most obvious approaches here will be an SQRT-decomposition or a segment tree which allow you to update and search for O(sqrt(n)) and O(log(n)) respectively.
